# Make list from two database items

Tags: android, database, list

I want to make a list from some data that I have in my database.

The first two sets of data in my database are first name and last name.

I want my list to show both first and last name instead of now where it only shows the first name. How do I do that? My code looks like this:

```
    private void fillData() 
{
     Cursor contactCursor = mDbHelper.fetchAllReminders();
     startManagingCursor(contactCursor);

     String[] from = new String[]{DbAdapter.KEY_FIRST};

     int[] to = new int[]{R.id.contactlist};

     SimpleCursorAdapter contacts = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.list, contactCursor, from, to);
     setListAdapter(contacts);

}
```

Comment: Have you tried making a custom list adapter?

Comment: You can go for custom list Adapter and use the LayoutInflate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a full implementation. You will need to create a custom row and a custom Array adapter.
Here is a full tutorial http://commonsware.com/Android/excerpt.pdf

This will tell you everything you need to know to get this done.

Also refer here where ive posted another example.

[How to add an EditText to a ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7504868/how-to-add-a-editview-to-a-listview/7505010#7505010)

EDIT: How to build a custom listview and return data from a databse

You first create a listview activity.

```
public class meeting_list extends ListActivity {


Cursor model = null;
meetingAdapter adapter = null;

     //This should be what ever your database helper is from your SQLite base.
meetingHelper helper = null;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.meeting_list);
    helper = new meetingHelper(this);
    model = helper.getAll();
    startManagingCursor
    (model);


adapter = new meetingAdapter(model);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
    registerForContextMenu(getListView());

 //Ondestroy is used to close the database to free up resources
  @Override
public void onDestroy(){
    super.onDestroy();

    helper.close();
}

    @Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView list, View view, int position, long id){
    Intent i = new Intent(meeting_list.this, meeting_create_edit.class);

            //
    i.putExtra(ID_EXTRA, String.valueOf(id));

    startActivity(i);
}

//Here create a class to extend the Cursor Adapter
class meetingAdapter extends CursorAdapter{
    meetingAdapter(Cursor c){
        super(meeting_list.this, c);
    }




@Override
    public void bindView(View row, Context ctxt, Cursor c) {

        meetingHolder holder = (meetingHolder)row.getTag();
        holder.populateFrom(c, helper);

    }


@Override
    public View newView(Context ctxt, Cursor c, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
        View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mrow, parent, false);
        meetingHolder holder = new meetingHolder(row);
        row.setTag(holder);
        return row;
    }
}


//Here create a class to actually hold the view for the row in the listview.
static class meetingHolder{
    private TextView mtitle = null;
    private TextView maddress = null;
    private ImageView Icon = null;

    meetingHolder(View row){
        mtitle=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.mtitle);
        maddress = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.address);
        Icon = (ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.Micon);

    }

//Here populate the row with the data from your database
    void populateFrom(Cursor c, meetingHelper helper){

             mtitle.setText(helper.getMettingTitle(c));
             maddress.setText(helper.getAddress(c));
```

This should do it. Just substitute your informations where it should be. This is a tutorial ive put together for you.

Comment: You will basically just need to create a custom row with two textviews, one for first name and one for last name. And then you would want to override getView() when you create your custom adapter. The tutorial will give you everything you need to know.

Comment: Hey, I read the pdf and tried to make somthing but i cound not make it work. I cant se how to make it worke with me populating the list from a database. Could you make som kind of code the show me how to do it?

Comment: Post your code of what you have made so far. Ill tell you want you are doing wrong or need to do.

Comment: Post your code of what you tried to create from the tutorial.

Comment: From the code above you are doing it correctly. Using the simpleCursor adapter. How does your Extension of the ArrayAdapter look?

Comment: Hey. Im am having trouble with implanting the populate function and the meetingAdapter class, can someone give me an explination of the 2 parts? My code can be seen here: [link](http://peecee.dk/upload/view/338533)

Answer (score 0):

Now i have tried to edit the code according to your guide, what i have done for now looks like this:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);   
      setContentView(R.layout.main2);

      mDbHelper = new DbAdapter(this);
      mDbHelper.open();
      fillData();      

}

private void fillData() 
{
     Cursor contactCursor = mDbHelper.fetchAllReminders();
     startManagingCursor(contactCursor);

     String[] from = new String[]{DbAdapter.KEY_FIRST};

     int[] to = new int[]{R.id.contactlist};

     SimpleCursorAdapter contactsfirst = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.list, contactCursor, from, to);

     String[] from2 = new String[]{DbAdapter.KEY_LAST};

     int[] to2 = new int[]{R.id.contactlist};

     SimpleCursorAdapter contactslast = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.list, contactCursor, from2, to2);

     setListAdapter(contactsfirst,last);

}
```

And my xml file looks like this:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:orientation="horizontal"
 >
 <TextView
 android:id="@+id/first"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:textSize="40sp"
/>
<TextView
 android:id="@+id/last"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:textSize="40sp"
  />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: It looks like you are filling the data in correctly. Did you override the BaseAdapter? Is your list actually populating with anything?

Comment: How do i override the baseadapter? But the list dosent populate anything because the program want compile

Comment: LOL wow....Okay ill put something together for you right quick. You must have problems with the tutorial?

Comment: I think i understand the tutorial, but i could not accosiate it to my own problem.

Comment: Ohh okay got it. Give me a second and ill show you want you need to do in code. Give me a second